Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client' in next build (v14.1.4)
command: next build
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/reducers/server-action-reducer.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client'

./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/fetch-server-response.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client'

./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/action-client-wrapper.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client'

example usage in ./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/reducers/server-action-
reducer.js:
[const { createFromFetch, encodeReply } = !!process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME ? require("react-server-dom-webpack/client.edge") : require("react-server-dom-webpack/client");](https://stackoverflow.com)

Can you help me to fix this error?

Just change the /page folder in /src, for example, to the /webpages folder

It's working in my next js project. just rename the pages folder from src or remove it from src.
before:
src/pages
after:
src/Cpages
it's working fine
You can also remove the folder from src directory
